# What is a word or a phrase for a person who runs computer simulations?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns

I am looking for a word or a phrase that would refer to the person / agent / entity (not-necessarily human) who controls and can arbitrarily manipulate a computer simulation.

Example sentences:

- "If Nick Bostrom's [simulation hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulation_hypothesis) is correct, the _____ could make simulation changes, which, to us, would appear as strange or mysterious events."
- "[The sims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sims) continued with their days without realizing that their lives could be instantly changed by the _____'s decisions."
- "The ____ controlled the rules, parameters, and external events of the simulation of a network of cities and their inhabitants."

Criteria:

- Connotation: neutral/objective
- Register or level of speech: formal/academic but not necessarily
- Part of speech: noun

Similar words:

- *Simulator*: Refers to the machine or software that computes the simulation, I'm looking for a word that refers to the person/agent that chooses what to simulate and what manipulations/changes to make.
- *Player/Modeler/Scientist*: Implies that the purpose of the simulation is known: a video game, a mathematical study, or a scientific experiment. I'm looking for a general word that does not imply a specific purpose.
- *Deity/God*: The simulated people might call the person/agent that, but I'm looking for a word/phrase that is objective/perspective-independent.
- *Simulant/Simulacrum*: May refer to the simulation but not to the person/agent that controls it.

Comment: How about *controller* for the person who controls the simulation?

Comment: Did you know that a *computer* is a person who performs computations?

Comment: (But the obvious word to fit your scenario is "God".)

Comment: Merriam-Webster suggests [simulator](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/simulator). Other terms will work in specific contexts eg mad scientist.

Answer (score 3):

***User*** and ***operator*** are common terms for a person running or controlling any mechanism, including a software application. The term *operator* is more commonly used in this sense in the phrase *operator error*.

Answer (score 2):

I like ***creator***, a term often used to refer to our own existence (the creator of the universe, e.g.).

***Administrator*** may work as well if you think of the simulation as a "system", and the controller a system admin.

Answer (score 1):

Simularian came to mind however, there is no such word as far as I can tell in English. In spanish it appears that simularian is defined as "they/you would simulate". Not sure if it works though. Maybe someone fluent in spanish could chime in. Of course, English would never ste.. I mean "borrow" a word from another language.

When I was in the army years back there was a position usually filled by a junior officer known as "Directorate of Simulation". Seems to meet the "term or phrase" portion of the criteria.

As long as English doesn't have a word expressly meeting the criteria as presented it seems to me a perfect opportunity to delve into the productive morphological process of linguistics!

Ill go first.     Simulatorian
and second.       Simulatorialist

Answer (score 0):

I would go with proctor. I read this question days ago and the word proctor popped in my head today. A proctor is someone who monitors pupils during an examination... Which I believe would be the intent of someone who is putting you into a simulation anyway (to see how you react to certain situations or events).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).